# Simple openmp call for loop not working

Tags: openmp

I am writing some code that would definitively benefit from trying to integrate openmp some software that I am writing. I am new to openmp, and while testing some very basic test code (see below) I noticed that the execution times are extremely longer with openmp activated (#pragma line). Any insight is much appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    int number=200;
    int max = 2000000;

    for(int t=1; t<max; t++)
    {
        double fac = 0.0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:fac)
        for(int n=2; n<=number; n++)
            fac += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code will behave much better if you exchange the values of `number` and `max`.

Answer (score 1):

As currently written the code encounters the parallel region `max` times.  The overhead of entering a parallel region in an OpenMP program is small, but you incur it `2000000` times.  You don't actually tell us what the run times are, but I can readily believe that this makes the them *extremely longer* than the serial version. I suggest you wrap the outer loop in a parallel region, not the inner loop.

Take care when you rewrite your code to ensure that the payload inside the parallel region is significant, and returns some value(s) to the program outside the parallel region.  Absent these steps a crafty optimising compiler can determine that a loop returns nothing to the rest of the program and simply optimise it away.

Also insert some timing instructions (use `omp_get_wtime`), rerun your code and, if matters are still not satisfactory, update your question with the new information you gather.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is very helpful. Wrapping the outer loop radically reduces the times. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved code that actually works as intended. It basically wraps the outer loop, rather than the inner one. When compiled without openmp support it takes 1.49s, with openmp 0.48s.

```
int main()
{
    int number=200;
    int max = 2000000;

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int t=1; t<max; t++)
    {
        double fac = 0.0;

        for(int n=2; n<=number; n++)
            fac += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```